# Cannot import type constructor from installed package in Haskell

Tags: haskell, module

I'm trying to use the `Stream` type defined in [this package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Stream-0.4.7.2/docs/Data-Stream.html). After installing with with cabal, I tried defining the tail function on streams as a quick test :

```
import Stream  

tail' :: Stream a -> Stream a
tail' (Cons x s) = s
```

which gives me this error message :

```
test.hs:3:14: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class `Stream'
    Perhaps you meant `StreamT' (imported from Stream)

test.hs:3:26: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class `Stream'
    Perhaps you meant `StreamT' (imported from Stream)

test.hs:4:12: error: Not in scope: data constructor `Cons'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

after some searches, I thought the problem might be that importing the module does not automatically import the type constructor `Stream` and constructor `Cons` with it. So I changed it to

```
import Stream (Stream, Cons)

tail' :: Stream a -> Stream a
tail' (Cons x s) = s
```

after which I get

```
test.hs:1:20: error: Module `Stream' does not export `Stream'

test.hs:1:28: error: Module `Stream' does not export `Cons'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

and this is puzzling. Do I have to alter the installed package and add `Stream` and `Cons` to its export list? Or am I not importing the module correctly?

Comment: The package you link only has `Data.Stream`. You must be  importing something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing the wrong module; looking at the top of your link, the module name is `Data.Stream`. (`Stream` is the name of the package -- it names a collection of modules to be installed.) So things should work better if you write

```
import Data.Stream

tail' :: Stream a -> Stream a
tail' (Cons x s) = s
```

The fact that the incantation `import Stream` worked at all indicates to me that you have another package installed that provides this module, though I'm not sure which.